# How to force Web Browser control to always open web page in the same window?

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I need to use web  browser in my application as it keeps repetitive tasks from employees, but there is a problem with javascript that opens a new window in IE after clicking on anchor. How do I tell web browser control to "open new window" where I want it to be opened? For example in the other web browser control?

Comment: I'm interested in hearing the answer to this. But, wouldn't the component have to inform your application that a new window is to be opened? You would then have to open the new window with a new WebBrowser component. Maybe there's an event?

Comment: Unfortunately, the anchor is "javascript:void(0)" link.. I dunno how to solve this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out: [proof-of-concept of .NET System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser module using](http://dotbrowser.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dotbrowser/trunk/Browser.cs?view=markup) source code

---

My experience about that controls has given me a vision that this issue can tried to be solved in next steps:

1. always cancel [NewWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.newwindow.aspx) event
2. catch [all links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.links.aspx) clicking
3. but not all link can be cached this way, so I decided to parse all tags `<a>` manually on [Document Loading Completion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx)
4. in general, this control is very poor and has been made so by Microsoft deliberately. though there is powerful toolset around [Webrowser.Document.HtmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.domdocument.aspx) and namespace [MSHTML](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=128638)
5. an example of it's using is [HtmlElement.DomElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.domelement.aspx)

   ```
   foreach(HtmlElement tag in webBrowser.Document.All)        
   {
     switch (tag.TagName.ToUpper)
     {
       case "A":
       {
         tag.MouseUp += new HtmlElementEventHandler(link_MouseUp);
         break;
       }
     }
   }

   void link_MouseUp(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
   {
     HtmlElement link = (HtmlElement)sender;
     mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass a = (mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass)link.DomElement;
     switch (e.MouseButtonsPressed)
     {
       case MouseButtons.Left:
       {
         if ((a.target != null && a.target.ToLower() == "_blank") ||
             e.ShiftKeyPressed ||
             e.MouseButtonsPressed == MouseButtons.Middle)
         {
           // add new tab
         }
         else
         {
           // open in current tab
         }
         break;
       }
       case MouseButtons.Right:
       {
         // show context menu
         break;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

See more at the first link, that's the source code of main window, there are a lot of different manipulations there!

Comment: and How do I insert this into my application?

Comment: cool, there is the URL in A but I'd need to parse it cause it's part of onclick !!! GREAT. THANK YOU

Answer (score 15):

I found a simple solution that works.

```
private void WebBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(WebBrowser1.StatusText);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This code works fine (VS 2015, C#). No new window now. Easy to use and the snippet is small.

Comment: Very simple and nice solution that works for me too. Thank you!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why such a complex answer Guys? Abatischev, I'd be curious to see into your brain, should be interesting...

Just try this:

```
Private Sub WB1_NewWindow(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WB1.NewWindow
    newUrl = WB1.Url.ToString

    e.Cancel = True
    WB1.Navigate(newUrl)
End Sub
```

Now you may change the second line into WB2 or any other WebBrowser component in any of your OWN forms.

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in the case `MouseBUttons.Left`:

> Error 1   Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case
>   1048576:') to another C:\Documents and Settings\ever\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2005\Projects\Desarrollo\wApp_SurverMonkey\wApp_SurverMonkey\frmNetcare.cs    64  17  wApp_SurverMonkey