# how to open clickable link in new tab webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control, tabcontrol

I have a form with Tabcontrol that has 2 tab pages.... tabpage1 and tabpage2.

- Tabpage1 has webbrowser1 and tabpage2 has webbrowser2.
- webbrowser1 navigates to a URL, example will be yahoo.com.
- when I click on any of the links in yahoo.com, I would like that link to be opened in the tabpage2-webbrowser2.

I am new to vb.net, so please make it simple and not complicated, this is for school.

Comment: This has nothing to do with VB.NET. It has to do with how you specify the HTML attribute. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target)

Comment: @AndandKumar, please I said simple, your providing me with C# I need visual basic help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**1.Always cancel NewWindow event**

**2.Catch all links clicking**

Everything explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701746/how-to-force-webbrowser-component-to-always-open-web-page-in-the-same-window).

But the code is in C#. You need to check it with VB.NET.