# .NET Webbrowser Control Handle Form Submission In Current Page/Control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a situation where in my browser control user needs to fill and submit a form step by step. But issue is, in the source html/web page has form target as "_blank". so, when user tried to fill first page/form and submit it open the next form in Internet Explorer New Window (not in my browser control).

I tried following method but didn't work!

Method-1:

I change the form target attribute using following code:

```
objWebForm.webMain.Document.GetElementById("formID").SetAttribute("target", "_self")
```

but that didn't work and besides that i need to know form id that's not possible.

Method-2: 
I followed sam answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701746/how-to-force-web-browser-control-to-always-open-web-page-in-the-same-window)

```
private void WebBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(WebBrowser1.StatusText);
}
```

but that only works on link anchor tag. not on form target :(

so, any workaround for this ?

Comment: You could use httpclient class. Re-do the form in winform and use httpclient to submit your request. You can then control whatever is being sent and receive.

Comment: @user7452368 dear sir, i am not sending the form programmatically, user click on submit button. and also i don't need to control/handle the request and response. all i just need to open the new page/window that is initiated via form submission.